Is there a way to identify non-duplicates of a specific color in excel?
I look at very large excel sheets and I’m looking for a way to automate a process. Basically the sheet is a before and after for code locations. I will link an example image of the sheet.
I’m looking for a way to identify lines in red that do not have a corresponding green line (the code was removed but not added anywhere). Is there a macro that I could write to help me identify that? It’s not the same as a de-dup because there will be codes that are green with no red counterpart and that is fine.
Link to example (photo) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ed-gMMQG0jSaTRUj2i3OklkTSWQ44Byx/view?usp=sharing

If you simply need to check whether there's a second value for the code, you check with a COUNTIFS.
In an additional column, I check with countifs if the code appears more than once, if it does it labels the row accordingly. If you need it to only verify on the first example you can also add an AND formula and check that column D is blank. However, for this it would group the second instance the same way as a case where there isn't a second line, so we add an additional IF statement to check whether Column C is blank before giving it that distinction.
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,A2)>1,"Yes","No")

=IF(AND(ISBLANK(D2),COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,A2)>1),"Yes",IF(ISBLANK(C2),"Exclude","No"))

